# How to JOIN multiple times the same table to retrieve different results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I need to request the records from the same time but don't know how to separate them one from another to not get them merged.

There is a table `categories` with column `CID` which represent *Component ID* to separate the categories:

```
id  cid     title
1   1       News
2   1       Events

3   2       Users
4   2       Administrators

5   3       Guests
6   3       Registered
```

And here is a `components` table:

```
id  title
1   Content
2   Members
3   Access level
```

I need to retrieve a results from a database so I could print these variables in my `content_list_view.php`:

```
<?php foreach($results as $item):?>
    ID: <?php echo $item->id;?> <br/>
    Title: <?php echo $item->title;?> <br/>
    Category: <?php echo $item->category;?> <br/>
    Access: <?php echo $item->access;?> <br/>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecords, I'm doing a query in `content_model.php`:

```
public function get_content_list(){

    $this->db
        ->select('
            content.id,
            content.title,
            categories.title AS category,
            categories.title AS access
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'content.catid = categories.id')
        ->join('categories AS alvl', 'content.alvl = alvl.id');

    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table_name);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query->result();
    else
        return FALSE;

}
```

After all, this is what I get in my view, *Category* and *Access* are the same. Access should be **Registered** :

```
ID: 1
Title: Some article test news
Category: News
Access: News
```

Any advice how to separate the records when JOINING tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is into the select, because you aren't assign `alvl` and it takes always from `categories`
try to change this:

```
$this->db
        ->select('
            content.id,
            content.title,
            categories.title AS category,
            categories.title AS access
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'content.catid = categories.id')
        ->join('categories AS alvl', 'content.alvl = alvl.id');
```

to this:

```
$this->db
        ->select('
            content.id,
            content.title,
            categories.title AS category,
            alvl.title AS access
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'content.catid = categories.id')
        ->join('categories AS alvl', 'content.alvl = alvl.id');
```

Comment: wow! i didn't even know I can do it in that way. THanks a lot Alessandro

Comment: Glad to help you, I'm passing for this problem, and first time isn't so clear how to do @aspirinemaga